# Pantech Impact ubuntu bluetooth connection?

Tags: ubuntu-9.10, connection, bluetooth, file-transfer

I do not understand how to pair my new pantech impact with my ubuntu laptop so that I can send pictures and files back and forth.

Can anyone provide instructions?

Answer (score 0):

Right-click on the Bluetooth icon in the system tray and pick `Set up new device...`, then hit the `Forward` button. Put the phone in discoverable/announce state. Pick the device when it shows up. The computer will give you a PIN to enter. Enter said PIN into the phone. Phone is now paired with the computer.

Comment: there was no bluetooth icon in my tray, and when i manually start the bluetooth app in ubuntu there is no adapter detected, so it doesn't show the icon unless i set it to.  how do i enable the built in adapter?

Comment: First make sure that it's not disabled by a killswitch or similar. Then... well, on Fedora there's a `bluetooth` service that has to be running in order for it to work, but I'm not sure if Ubuntu has something similar.

Comment: all killswitches disengaged, and I'm not sure how to tell if that service is running.

Comment: You can use `ps` for that purpose.